# Switch activities while already within a tab

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-activity

I have a swipeable tab layout in my android application, I wanted to make a switchable activity within my second tab (maybe using a toggle button) that would switch between a list view that's populated from a database and Google maps api which would dot the same data on the map using the longitude and latitude from the data in the database.

Wondering if this is possible, bare in mind I already have the tabs on the top of the screen so to add a toggle button would have to be with the activity that's shown by default but when clicked would switch from the list view activity to the google maps api and switch back etc

Comment: The tabs consists of Fragments and not activities right? I got a bit confused with the title. The toggle button you want won't be part of the tabbed UI (lets say its in the default activity that's totally unrelated to the tablayout)? I think you can try out setting a SharedPreferences variable and when the specific index in the Tab Layout is called, it will check for its value for you to specify a ListView or a MapsView.

Comment: So using a shared preference variable I can toggle between fragments and alpoligies still new to android @adjuremods

Comment: Yes, basically when that specific index is called in the tab change event, you can call the SharedPreferences variable (or store it on a variable somewhere), and check if its supposed to be in ListView mode or MapsView mode.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to link to xml documents to the class where the shared preference variable is ?